# Codename One: Strange toolbar animation on form change

Tags: codenameone

Since adding a global Toolbar to the forms there is a strange animation bug (?) when changing forms. At hitting a Button at FormA that will invoke FormB.show() the title has an animation the lets the new form stutter in the toolbar area from the right to the left. After googling I found [this](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/animations.html):

[image]

This is pretty much the problem I face at the toolbar, only difference is the toolbar Logo I added to the center is stuttering from the right to the left to its place. After the animation is done, the form looks just like it should.

In the main I do this:

```
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
```

In every Form I do something like this in the constructor:

```
    menuForm = new Form(" ", new BorderLayout());
    logo = res_theme.getImage("Logo_Gema_vertikal.png");
    menuForm.getToolbar().getTitleComponent().setUIID("toolbar_image");
    ((Label)menuForm.getToolbar().getTitleComponent()).setIcon(logo);
    menuForm.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(homeCommand);
    menuForm.getToolbar().getMenuBar().addCommand(homeCommand);
```

If I leave out adding the logo to the toolbar, only the Command Icons are flying from the right to the left. What is causing this? Am I using the toolbar wrong?

Comment: Could you post a video illustrating the animation issue?

Comment: Added. Please see the edit.

Comment: Its only a Screenshot, if it doesnt suit I can add a video as well.

Comment: That's sufficient, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it's due to using the default animation which is `createSlideFadeTitle`. You can solve this by changing the animation of the current form and the destination form to either `createCover` or `createSlide`:

In the current form:

```
currentForm.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, false, 300));
nextForm.show();
```

And in the destination form:

```
nextForm.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, false, 300));
currentForm.showBack();
```

Comment: Thank you very much once again, you have helped me quite a few times now :)